# jmeter - Clean up previously saved files before running a new test plan

Tags: jmeter

I have been using the following BeanShell script in order to delete all output files before each new run of a test plan

`import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
FileUtils.cleanDirectory(new File(vars.get("OutPutFolder")));`

My test plan consists of a Thread group that is using 100 users (number of threads) with a loop count of 5.

I have tried several ways to incorporate the aforementioned beanshell script but i cannot seem to find the right place to put it in.

Things that i have already tried:

- Creating a new "setup thread group" ("Run thread groups consecutively" is checked)

  and place script in a beanshell samples > Files do get deleted but outcome files are not persisted to the disk (re-deleted by my script)

  and place script in a beanchsell PreProcessor > Files do not get deleted
- Placing script in my main Thread group > Files do get deleted but outcome files are not persisted to the disk (re-deleted by my script)
- Using an If Controller (`${__BeanShell(vars.getIteration() == 1)} && ${__threadNum} == 1`)

Comment: which problem are you trying to solve by deleting files: 1 - next run may not have enough disk space to run or 2 - logs of next run mix up with logs of old run? Two different situations / solutions. Also is it for specific OS, or does it have to be cross-platform?

Comment: Hi Kiril. I am trying to solve the 2nd problem. It does not have to be cross platform solution, currently running jMeter on linux (centOS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not solving your problem, but based on your comment, here's a different simple solution, which provides you with ability to separate current test results from previous test results.

All the listeners in JMeter can accept a dynamic file path, and one of the dynamic values they can use is `TESTSTART.MS` property (see [here](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#predefinedprops)), which will be different for each test execution.

So in order to make name of each output file (or report) unique for the run you can use that property in the name of the output file:

```
your/path/${TESTSTART.MS}_errors.csv
```

You can even create a sub-folder holding set of the output files for specific execution, like this:

```
your/path/${TESTSTART.MS}/name1.ext
your/path/${TESTSTART.MS}/name2.ext
```

That way the names never collide, and they are grouped by execution (all files from the same execution will have the same timestamp, so you can filter them).

On top of that, on linux you could use [logrotate](http://www.linuxcommand.org/man_pages/logrotate8.html) to zip old jmeter logs (and since they are just text files, they zip nicely)

Comment: Thank you Kiril for your well documented solution. I also had to add some BeanShell scripting in order to dynamically create some directories as "save responses to a file" sampler does not work if the target directory does not exist. It is not the solution i was looking for but its certainly better than having to manually delete files before running new test plans.